# What is UserPreferenceChangedEventHandler in C# winform applications?

Tags: winforms, c#-3.0

I found some of my winform application controls, such as DataGridView and ToolStrips, are referred to by UserPreferenceChangedEventHandlers. I have no idea what setting of the controls will generate such references and why such references keep my control alive in memory. How can I remove such references from that event? Thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It is the delegate type for the SystemEvents.UserPreferenceChanged event.  This event fires when Windows broadcasts the WM_SETTINGCHANGE message.  Which typically happens when the user uses a control panel applet and changes a system setting.

Several controls register an event handler for this event, DataGridView, DateTimePicker, MonthCalendar, ProgressBar, PropertyGrid, RichTextBox, ToolStrip, NumericUpDown.  They typically are interested in font or cue changes and anything that would affect the layout.

SystemEvents.UserPreferenceChanged is a static event.  Registering a handler and forgetting to unregister it causes a memory leak, it prevents the control from being garbage collected.  The listed controls ensure this doesn't happen, they unregister the event handler in either the OnHandleDestroyed() or the Dispose() method.

You'll get in trouble when neither of those two methods run.  That will happen when you remove the control from the container's Controls collection and forget to Dispose() it.  While forgetting to call Dispose() is not normally a problem, it is a hard requirement for controls.  It is easy to forget too, controls are normally automatically disposed by the Form.  But that only happens for controls in the Controls collection.

Also be sure to call Dispose() on forms that you display with the ShowDialog() method, after you obtained the dialog results.  The using statement is the best way to handle that.

---

One more excruciating detail is important about the UserPreferenceChanged event, it is often the one that deadlocks your app when you create controls on a worker thread.  Typically when the workstation is locked (press Win+L).  Which cannot come to a good end when you use the controls I listed, the SystemEvents class tries to raise the event on the UI thread but of course cannot do this correctly when more than one thread has created them.

Also the kind of bug that can have a lasting effect, a splash screen for example can get the SystemEvents class to guess wrong about which thread is your UI thread.  After which it then permanently raises the event on the wrong thread.  Very ugly [to diagnose](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dsui_team/2012/10/31/debugging-windows-forms-application-hangs-during-systemevents-userpreferencechanged/), the deadlock is well hidden.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I checked the code and it seems the problematic control was added to to control list of a panel and the panel was added to the control list of another panel and finally the root panel was added to the form's control list. From the memory profiler I can also see that the control's dispose method was called but the UserPreferenceChangedEventHandler still hangs. This is the part that I don't understand. Is there any other things that I missed?

Comment: Nice answer BUT as Steve mentions, sometimes even though you'll dispose the control, you still have this issue. There are several Connect entries about this problem such as: http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/469277/toolstrip-statusstrip-toolstriptextbox-visibility-and-userpreferencechangedeventhandler.