# Why is this DataGridView still referenced by a UserPreferenceChangedEventHandler?

Tags: .net, winforms, memory-leaks, memory-profiling

I upgraded a .NET 2.0 Winform Application build with VS2005 to .NET 3.5 SP1. build by VS 2008

The application had a memory leak in .NET 2.0 caused by a ToolStripControl that was referenced by a UserPreferenceChangedEventHandler.

Upgrading to .NET 3.5 fixed the issue. I still have a problem with DataGridViews.

They are also referenced by a  UserPreferenceChangedEventHandler.

Are there some common problems with DataGridViews that prevent forms containing them not being recycled by the garbage collector?

[Instance Retention Graph](http://www.freeimagehosting.net/4545b)

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1137071/what-is-userpreferencechangedeventhandler-in-c-sharp-winform-applications

Comment: @Stuart At the end it realy was what you suggested: A controll was removed and not disposed. It was a TabPage that contained a DataGridView. At some point Tab.TabPages.RemoveAt(1) was called.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For anything implementing `IDisposable` you should call `Dispose()`. `DataGridView` is one of those... which in turn ensures that it unregisters the static event handler you mention...

Comment: When I have a DataGridView on a Form, what would be good Event of the Form to call Dispose  for the DateGridView?

Comment: For some reason I realy had to call dispose for one of the DataGridViews of the form.